# Load all csv/txt files from one directory and merge them via python

Tags: python, file, python-2.7, csv, directory

I have a folder which contains hundreds (possibly over 1 k) of csv data files, of chronological data. Ideally this data would be in one csv, so that I can analyse it all in one go. What I would like to know is, is there a way to append all the files to one another using python.

My files exist in folder locations like so:

```
C:\Users\folder\Database Files\1st September
C:\Users\folder\Database Files\1st October
C:\Users\folder\Database Files\1st November
C:\Users\folder\Database Files\1st December
etc
```

Inside each of the folders there is 3 csv (I am using the term csv loosly since these files are actually saved as .txt files containing values seperated by pipes `|`)

Lets say these files are called:

```
MonthNamOne.txt
MonthNamTwo.txt
MonthNameOneTwoMurged.txt
```

How would I, or even is it possible to code something to go through all of these folders in this directory and then merge together all the `OneTwoMurged.txt` files?

Comment: Start by learning how to use `os.path.walk()`.  That will give you a simple way to find all the files.  Forget about the `csv` part until you've mastered that much.  Then the rest will be easy :-)  - or start with the simpler `os.walk()` instead.  Less confusing at first.

Comment: If you happen to have bash msys or cygwin you can just `cat mydir/**/*OneTwoMurged.txt > my_merged_file.txt`

Comment: @TimPeters since `os.path.walk` is deprecated and no longer in 3.x anyway, I think the OP should just ignore `os.path.walk`.

Comment: @JonClements, good advice, Jon!  I agree.

Comment: Any recommendations on what I should be looking into as oppose to `os.path.walk` ?? Thanks

Comment: [os.walk](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk)

Comment: Also `glob.glob()`although `cat` is easier...

Comment: Do the files all have the same headers?  Do they have a column containing information stored in the directory name/file name, or would you need to add a column telling a text file that it's from 1st December?  (It would make things easier if you'd edit in a few lines from the start of a sample file, assuming they all look the same.)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For all files in folder with `.csv` suffix

```
import glob
import os

filelist = []

os.chdir("folderwithcsvs/")
for counter, files in enumerate(glob.glob("*.csv")):
    filelist.append(files)
    print "do stuff with file:", files, counter

print filelist

for fileitem in filelist:
    print fileitem
```

Obviously the "do stuff part" depends on what you want done with the files, this is looking getting your list of files.

If you want to do something with the files on a monthly basis then you could use datetime and create possible months, same for days or yearly data.

For example, for monthly files with the names `Month Year.csv` it would look for each file.

```
import subprocess, datetime, os

start_year, start_month = "2001", "January"

current_month = datetime.date.today().replace(day=1)
possible_month = datetime.datetime.strptime('%s %s' % (start_month, start_year), '%B %Y').date()
while possible_month <= current_month:
    csv_filename = possible_month.strftime('%B %Y') + '.csv'
    month = possible_month.strftime('%B %Y').split(" ")[0]
    year = possible_month.strftime('%B %Y').split(" ")[1]
    if os.path.exists("folder/" + csv_filename):
        print csv_filename
    possible_month = (possible_month + datetime.timedelta(days=31)).replace(day=1)
```

Obviously you can change that to however you feel fit, let me know if you need more or if this suffices.

Comment: is it possible to go for a Month Year.csv and if it exists then do stuff part?

Comment: @AEA So like: `Novemember 2013.csv`?

Comment: yeh that is exactly what i need :)

Comment: works perfectly, will give you bounty when the time has elapsed (19 hours as we speak)

Answer (score 5):

This will recursively process a directory, match a specific file pattern for processing, and append the results of processed files.  This will parse the csvs as well, so you could do individual line analysis and processing as well.  Modify as needed :)

```
#!python2
import os
import fnmatch
import csv
from datetime import datetime as dt

# Open result file
with open('output.txt','wb') as fout:
    wout = csv.writer(fout,delimiter='|')

    # Recursively process a directory
    for path,dirs,files in os.walk('files'):

        # Sort directories for processing.
        # In this case, sorting directories named "Month Year" chronologically.
        dirs.sort(key=lambda d: dt.strptime(d,'%B %Y'))
        interesting_files = fnmatch.filter(files,'*.txt')

        # Example for sorting filenames with a custom chronological sort "Month Year.txt"
        for filename in sorted(interesting_files,key=lambda f: dt.strptime(f,'%B %Y.txt')):

            # Generate the full path to the file.
            fullname = os.path.join(path,filename)
            print 'Processing',fullname

            # Open and process file
            with open(fullname,'rb') as fin:
                for line in csv.reader(fin,delimiter='|'):
                    wout.writerow(line)
```

Comment: Like Tom Clements said in the comments `os.path.walk` is deprecated and no longer in 3.x anyway, I think the OP should just ignore `os.path.walk`.

Comment: @DennisSylvian, this is `os.walk` not `os.path.walk`.

Comment: there is problem with chronology, this code will acces files in random os-dependent order

Comment: @alko, Well that depends on file content.  If the content has dates in the csv lines it wouldn't matter.  If it doesn't have date information merging it into one file would be ambiguous, but we don't have any information on the content.

Comment: @MarkTolonen: I asked the OP about that for exactly that reason, to know if we'd have to push information in the names down into the csv.  No response yet.

Comment: Updated with an example of specifying the sort order for processing directories and files.

Answer (score 3):

Reading into pandas dataframe (choice of axis depends on your application), my example adds columns of same length

```
import glob
import pandas as pd


df=pd.DataFrame()
for files in glob.glob("*.csv"):
    print files 
    df = pd.concat([df,pd.read_csv(files).iloc[:,1:]],axis=1)
```

`axis = 0` would add row-wise

Comment: @Mogsdad What if your csvs have different numbers of rows, but the same number of columns. How would you edit this for 4 csvs (3 with 2 rows, and 1 with 3 rows) that all have two columns?

Comment: @JMeo - You should post that as a new question.